# couldn't identify the current cell object when I click on the Custom button of UITableView cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have created two custom button in UITableView.when i click on button1 the other button should be visible. for that i use following code. i am using UITableView grouped data type.

```
   btnSettingButton=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(265, 50, 22, 22)];
[btnSettingButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Settings Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnSettingButton addTarget:self action:@selector(accessoryButtonTapped:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[view addSubview:btnSettingButton];
[btnSettingButton setHidden:YES];



btnUncheck=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(265, 15, 18, 18)];

//btnUncheck=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnUncheck.tag=indexPath.row;
[btnUncheck setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NO.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [btnUncheck addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[view addSubview:btnUncheck];   
[btnUncheck release];

[cell.contentView addSubview:view];

return cell;



 - (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender event:(id)event
{
CGPoint touchPosition = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.tableV];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableV indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPosition];
if(favoriteChecked==NO)
   {


    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YES.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    if(indexPath){
    [btnSettingButton setHidden:NO];
    }
    favoriteChecked=YES;


   }
   else
   {


    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NO.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnSettingButton setHidden:YES];
    favoriteChecked=NO;
   }


}
```

when i use this code it shows the setting button to the last cell of the section.

please guide me how can i show settingButton to the cell which is clicked.

Comment: have you added your buttons in cellForRowAtIndexPath ? or its custom cells ?

Answer (score 1):

You only have one global variable for the btnSettingButton - of course it points to the last button you created.

You have to keep all references to all setting buttons you created, and then get the right one in your buttonTapped function. You could do it for example by adding all references to a dictionary, using the btnUncheck as a key - the btnUncheck is the sender you get in the button clicked function, so you can get the corresponding btnSettingButton from the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I am not clearly getting you.

I think you want to add a button in cell of tableview. If you click on this button , this image should be changed..

Am i right?

Comment: shweta can you come on chat? this is the link?     [http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4437/discussion-between-gopesh-gupta-and-martin-ullrich]